# Show a message when doing synchronous server request

Tags: android

I am working on an app where i do some calls in **synchronized** manner using the

```
class HttpUtil extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>
{...}

HttpUtil httpUtil = new HttpUtil();

httpUtil.execute((Void[]) null).get();
```

This will call to a AsyncTask method.

**Issue:**

The spinning wheel is not shown in the UI since we do a UI blocked request. Even if I add a toast then the toast is displayed after the request is completed.

If I make asynchronous calls then I get the spinning wheel as the UI was not blocked

**Expected:**

I need to show a spinning wheel for the blocked request(done adding get() method) also.

Comment: In case of downvote please do provide some comments so that i can improve the question. Since i can't share a complete code i can provide some comments.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not** use `get()` on a network operation. Just don't. Your app will freeze, and either get killed by the system, or the user will be frustrated that your app blocks the **entire UI of the system.** It's absolutely unacceptable, and there is **no** reason why a well-designed app should need to resort to that.

You turn on your indeterminate progress in the `AsyncTask`'s `onPreExecute()`, and turn it off in `onPostExecute()`. These two methods are always run on the UI threat. Please refer to the [documentation for AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Further, you won't need to pass `Void[] null` to the `execute()` call -- just pass nothing, which will result in an empty array of Void.

If any other operations or UI updates depend on the result of the request, then do those updates in `onPostExecute`. If you want to create modality to essentially "halt" the UI while the request is running, then display a dialog box, but please provide a cancel option.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Have upvoted as it may be helpful to others. But in my case i am looking for some other solution

Comment: You might want to explain *why* you are looking for some other answer, as what you are trying to do is not just "not recommended" by Android/Google, but discouraged to the point of causing an exception (NetworkOnMainthreadException) if you attempt to do it. Like I said in my answer, there's no reason why an Android app would require a synchronous, blocking network call. Please explain why you think you do, and maybe we can help you around that.